# NumPy type hint that something is both an array and float32?

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting

How can I type hint that a value being returned by a function is *both* an NumPy array and holds NumPy float32 data?

I can specify that the returned value is an array using:

```
def func() -> np.ndarray:
    ...
```

However, this does not enforce the knowledge that it is a float32 array.

I can specify that the returned value is of type float32 using:

```
def func() -> np.float32:
    ...
```

However, this does not enforce the knowledge that it is an array (as opposed to a singular scalar value).

Is there a way I can get both specified in the return type?

Comment: @Georgy, I agree that it's close enough. I apologize for not finding that question originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently impossible but is a popular feature request; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370) which contains information on progress and possible workarounds.